Alert when an item is shared with everyone
I have an interesting request from our security. They would like to receive an alert when something (site, library, file...) in our SharePoint Online tenant is shared with the "everyone except external users" group.
I did some research, but looks like I can only set up Alert policies based on the initiator, so shared by. So, this doesn't work.
Did anyone had similar request and found any solution?

I would look into audit log based approach.

Use Exchange PowerShell to search audit log for specific events in unattended way.
Create an Azure Function scheduled to run e.g. hourly and the code would search through audit log and send notifications in case somebody shared something with everyone.


Search the audit log
Create a PowerShell function in Azure

